# Problem with lsb-desktop-amd64

Tags: 64-bit, lsb-release

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and I was originally trying to run a installation for a program I've downloaded for Ubuntu.

When I run the program I am told that I need to have [Linux Standard Base](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/lsb/start) 3.1 installed and that I lack 3 modules in my system:

```
core-3.1-noarch
core-3.1-amd64
desktop-3.1-amd64
```

The Terminal tells me I can install the modules by running this comandline in my Terminal: `apt-get install lsb-desktop-amd64`

When I run the following command line in my terminal (`sudo apt-get install lsb-desktop-amd64`) I get the response that `E: can not locate the package lsb-desktop-amd64`.

What do I do? Please help if you have any clues!

N.B. I am new to Ubuntu so any detailed descriptions would be appreciated :-)

Best regards Mathias

Comment: Note: "The LSB has been criticized[13][14][15][16] for not taking input from projects, most notably the Debian project, outside the sphere of its member companies." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base Their list of compliant systems https://www.linuxbase.org/lsb-cert/productdir.php?by_lsb is empty.

Comment: So what is the program "you downloaded for Ubuntu"?

Comment: It's a online dictionary - Ordbogen.com
The file name is: ordbogsprogrammet-3.2.1-linux64.run
I downloaded it from this site: https://www2.ordbogen.com/downloads/# and I chose the 64-bit Linux version

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo apt install lsb`.

That will install Linux Standard Base.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but after I have succesfully installed the Linux Standard Base I still have the same problem, so it's unfortunately not the solution to my problem.